# How would I generate a linked chain of nodes with specified length?

Tags: python, data-structures

so I have the Node class as follows

```
class Node:

    def __init__(self, init_data):
        self.data = init_data
        self.next = None


    def get_data(self):
        return self.data


    def get_next(self):
        return self.next


    def set_data(self, new_data):
        self.data = new_data


    def set_next(self, new_next):
        self.next = new_next


    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.data)
```

now I want to create a function called

```
generate_chain(start,length):
```

This function should return a linked chain of Node objects where the first data value is equal to the starting number, each subsequent data value is 1 greater than the last, and the total number of nodes in the chain is equal to the chain length.

```
x = generate_chain(10, 5)

current = x
while current != None:
    print(current, end = ' ')
    current = current.get_next()
```

would yield

```
10 11 12 13 14
```

This was my way of trying the approach but I just encountered an error after the second Node

```
def generate_chain(num,length):
    n = Node(num)
    n.set_data(num)
    while length != 0:
        x = n.get_data()
        n.set_data(x)
        n.set_next(x+1)
        length -= 1
    return n
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following:

```
def generate_chain(num,length):
    n = Node(num)
    if length > 0:
        n.set_data(num)
        n.set_next(num+1)
        generate_chain(num+1, length-1)
        print(n)
    else:
        return n


print(generate_chain(10, 5))
```

It's recursive and it calls itself as long as length is bigger than 0.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```py
class Node:

    def __init__(self, init_data):
        self.data = init_data
        self.next = None

    def get_data(self):
        return self.data

    def get_next(self):
        return self.next

    def set_data(self, new_data):
        self.data = new_data

    def set_next(self, init_data):
        self.next = self._set_next(init_data)

    @classmethod
    def _set_next(cls, init_data):
        return cls(init_data)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.data)

def generate_chain(num,length):
    first = Node(num)
    num += 1
    _next = first
    for i in range(1,length):
        _next.set_next(num)
        _next = _next.get_next()
        num +=1
    return first
```

Answer (score 1):

What you did not consider in your code snippet, is that you have to create an instance of class `Node` for every single node.

Here is my approach. Might be not that efficient or elegant as other solutions, but my focus was on clearity on what happens:

```
def generate_chain(num,length):
    start = Node(num)  # Create start node
    length -= 1
    num +=1

    current_node = start  # Set the current node we want to work on
    while length != 0:
        next_node = Node(num)  # Create a new node
        current_node.set_next(next_node)  # Set the new node as next to current node
        length -= 1
        num +=1

        current_node = next_node  # Set the new created node as current node

    return start
```

Comment: How does this differ from my answer? Except that I moved the creation of a new node inside of the class definition.

Comment: Not much for sure, but I assume that creating the `Node` explicitly is easier to understand than hiding creaton behind a `@classmethod`.